# Remove an Application Pool in SharePoint 2010 that contain a hyphen in title

Tags: 2010, powershell

As the subject says - i'm trying to remove an application pool using the SP Management Shell (using Administrator).

I have a pool named **SharePoint - User Profiles**

I try to remove this app pool by running the **remove-spserviceapplicationpool** command
and then typing **SharePoint - User Profiles** and it blows up on me...

Here's an example of the input/output:

PS C:\Users\shsetup> remove-spserviceapplicationpool

cmdlet Remove-SPServiceApplicationPool at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Identity: SharePoint - User Profiles

Remove-SPServiceApplicationPool : Object not found.
At line:1 char:32
+ remove-spserviceapplicationpool <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Share...ApplicationPo
   ol:SPCmdletRemoveI...ApplicationPool) [Remove-SPServiceApplicationPool], I
  nvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletRemoveIi
   sWebServiceApplicationPool

Remove-SPServiceApplicationPool : Object reference not set to an instance of an
 object.
At line:1 char:32
+ remove-spserviceapplicationpool <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...ApplicationPool:
   SPCmdletRemoveI...ApplicationPool) [Remove-SPServiceApplicationPool], Null
  ReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletRemoveIi
   sWebServiceApplicationPool

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks,
Taps

Comment: I have the exact same issue, was your issue resolved??
There is no typo and the Get-spserviceapplicationpool does list the object Name ProcessAccountName
---- ------------------
SecurityTokenServiceApplicationPool BROWER\SPP_Admin
SharePoint - User Profiles BROWER\SPP_Ups but Remove-SPServiceApplicationPool -Identity "SharePoint - User Profiles" does not work
neither does,
Remove-SPServiceApplicationPool "SharePoint - User Profiles" Any help is appreciated!! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyphen in name of the service application pool is not a problem. I just created and removed it without any problem. Make sure there is no typo. Also make sure make sure it is listed in Get-spserviceapplicationpool

Answer (score 2):

Try: remove-spserviceapplicationpool -identity "SharePoint - User Profiles"

That should help.

Answer (score 0):

Tip: I found out that when I tried to use
"remove-spserviceapplicationpool [Applicationpool name]" and 
"remove-spserviceapplicationpool [GUID]" 
both returned "object not found" and "object reference not set to an instance of an object"
However, 
"get-spserviceapplicationpool | select name,id" 
did return the AppPool listed with all the other AppPools. 
Tried many things before I found out that there was an unintentional space in the AppPoolName. As soon as I entered the AppPoolName with quotationmarks, leaving the space where it was, I had no problems removing it... 
So, yes, this was a typo, but one where I least expected it to be. I wonder whether this incorrect use of the naming of the AppPool was what caused the errors in my Search Service App...